# How to get Invoice data in magento?

Tags: magento, collections, invoice

i am trying here ,
see i am getting order data but, i am not getting any $order->hasInvoice()

```
$orderID = 100000062;
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderID);
if ($order->hasInvoices()) {
    $invIncrementIDs = array();
    foreach ($order->getInvoiceCollection() as $inv) {
        $invIncrementIDs[] = $inv->getIncrementId();
    } Mage::log($invIncrementIDs);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please try the following code:

```
$orders_invoice = Mage::getModel("sales/order_invoice")->getCollection();

foreach($orders_invoice as $val) { 
  print_r($val->getData()); 
}
```

Comment: but i am getting blank brother